# can't use another account when testing in angularfire2 app

Tags: firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using Angularfire2 Typescript, I have finished my testing application but whenever I try to login with another facebook account with ingconito. It showing me an error that I dont have any permission as test user.

Does that mean that i have to set up my other account on firebase too? Or when I deploy it my app using firebase tool. It will work? I want to make it sure first. Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing using a facebook test user? If so, the Facebook test user has to be created for the same facebook client app that you configured for Firebase.

Comment: Yes. But actually, i want to know if I deploy my app, it would allow others to log in with facebook?

Comment: Make sure the Facebook test users belong to the same app. If you create 2 facebook projects: app1 and app2 and then set you facebook client and secret in the firebase console for app1. You cannot use Facebook test users for app2 while testing your Firebase app. The test users have to be created for app1.